# How to sum the values of two collections in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, summarizing, data-collection

I'm using GLDAS image collection in Google Earth Engine, and what a want is to sum four bands for a specific time like 10 years, and to obtain a collection with the sum date by date of the four bands:

eg:

SoilMoisture = SoilMoi0_10cm_inst+ SoilMoi10_40cm_inst+ SoilMoi100_200cm_inst + SoilMoi40_100cm_inst + SoilMoi100_200cm_inst

But if I use `var image3 = image1.add(image2)`, this is just for a single image, not a sum for collections.

Does someone know how to do this??

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `map` to apply a function to each image of an ImageCollection. Additionally, you can use `expression` to define the bands sum.

```
// Map a function to each image in the ImageCollection
var soilMoi = col.map(function(image){
  // Use expression to make the sum of the bands of interest
  var totalMoi = ee.Image(image).expression(
    // Mathematical expression
    'im1 + im2 + im3 + im4', {
      // Dictionary to link the terms in the expression to certain bands
      'im1': ee.Image(image).select('SoilMoi0_10cm_inst'),
      'im2': ee.Image(image).select('SoilMoi10_40cm_inst'),
      'im3': ee.Image(image).select('SoilMoi40_100cm_inst'),
      'im4': ee.Image(image).select('SoilMoi100_200cm_inst')
      // Rename the new band
      }).rename('SoilMoiAll');
  // Return the original image with the totalMoi band
  return ee.Image(image).addBands(totalMoi);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But this is to reduce to a single image, and what I am looking for more specifically, is the sum of the four bands date by date, and to have a collection with the total soil moisture for each date for example.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the explanation. I'll edit the answer.